How to get Result Table Column Information of a Query?
With This Query I can get an existing Table information.
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE table_name = 'Address'

But What I want To get is the Result Table Column Information. Suppose the Query and the Result Table is:
SELECT E.EmployeeName, A.AddressName
FROM Employee E
INNER JOIN Address A ON E.AddressId = A.AddressId


Result Table :



EmployeeName
AddressName




EmployeeName 1
AddressName 2


EmployeeName 3
AddressName 4



I want to get the column name, Column Data Type and Other Properties.

Which API/environment?

siggemannen Thanks for the help.
I used sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set to get result set details.
Here is the query:
DECLARE @Query nvarchar(max)= N''
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(@Query,NULL,0)

